# how to show multiple alerts in html web page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have web page in which there is check button if one button is selected then it shows one alert and if two then it should show two alerts but it shows only alert one of the button which is selected first .

I am using following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email_multiple").click(function(){
        var n = $("input:checked").length;
        //alert(n);
        //for(var i=1;i<=$("input:checked").length;i++){alert(n);}
        if(!($("input:checked").length)){
            alert('Please make a check on check box field thanks hahahahha...');
            return false;
        }
        if(n==1){
            var bb = $("input:checked").val();
            alert(bb);
            presenter.command("emailSend",{
                "toEmail": "",
                "toName": "",
                "subject": "",
                "body": "Single Attachment",
                "bodyHtml":"",
                 "attachments": ["/images/Animal/pdf/"+bb+".pdf"]
            }); 
            $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
        }
        if(n==2){
            var bb = $("input:checked").val();
            alert(bb);
            presenter.command("emailSend",{
                "toEmail": "",
                "toName": "",
                "subject": "",
                "body": "Single Attachment",
                "bodyHtml":"",
                 "attachments": ["/images/Animal/pdf/"+bb+".pdf","/images/Animal/pdf/"+bb+".pdf"]
            }); 
            $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You really need to format your code better..

Comment: You have to loop through all the checked values, not just one alert

Comment: if user selects two checkbox, then n will be 2. How do you expect it to go in the first **if** condition where it is checking for **n == 1**?

Comment: @SurajJadhav yes this is the problem but i added loop but it does not work can you please help me out

Comment: @Hanky Panky can you please help me out in this

Comment: what does your html look like?

Comment: @panpiper i have given in code please check that

Comment: @panpiper may i give you html code complete

Comment: why downvote it is valid question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email_multiple").click(function(){
        var n = $("input:checked").length;
        if(!($("input:checked").length)){
            alert('Please make a check on check box field thanks hahahahha...');
            return false;
        }
        for(var i=0; i < n; i++){
            var bb = $($("input:checked")[i]).val();
            alert(bb);
        }
    });
});
```